# Hardware requirements to build a strictly QUERYABLE archive node?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, full-node, hardware

I need to have a fully queryable and updating copy of the blockchain on my computer. I don't need it to be exactly synced to the blockchain, I don't need to validate the latest block, if it were a couple of blocks behind it wouldn't matter to me. I just need to query the entire historical blockchain. I would prefer to host it locally rather than use a service like quick node or infura because I'll also have a program running on the same computer constantly querying it.

Can I use HDD to do this? I assume I need minimum 15 TB.

Is there a way to make a queryable blockchain node that doesn't work validating?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer advocate from Chainstack here.

Based on the description, I would recommend using an [archive node](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/sync-modes#archive-nodes). You don't have to be a validator to use an archive node.
The size and syncing time depend on the Blockchain you are working on:

- Ethereum mainnet: ~12 TB
- Polygon mainnet: ~16 TB
- BNB Smart Chain: ~7 TB
- Fantom mainnet: ~4 TB
- Harmony mainnet: ~20 TB
- Avalanche mainnet: ~3 TB
- Solana mainnet: ~20 TB

[Source](https://chainstack.com/evm-nodes-a-dive-into-the-full-vs-archive-mode/)

Please take note that there are different types of clients too. For EVMs, an Erigon client consumes less disk space compared with a Geth client. In general, 15TB should be enough for Ethereum mainnet node.

Even though you say that you don't want to use a service provider(BTW Chainstack is a good service provider too), I still hope that you can give a second thought to this.

Fully syncing an archive node may take several days or even weeks to complete, and it is not an easy task to maintain an archive node as an individual.

Add on to original answer:

Both Geth and Erigon does not recommend using HDD([Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/hardware-requirements),[Erigon](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon))

[Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/hardware-requirements):

> Geth nodes rely on fast read and write operations. This means HDDs and
> cheaper HDDS can sometimes struggle to sync the blockchain.

[Erigon](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon):

> on HDD Erigon will always stay N blocks behind chain tip, but not fall
> behind.